# Session variable in CakePHP3

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I need to store some vital information (branch ID) when a user visits my website/app.
This information should be available in every controller. What I do is this:

**AppController.php**

```
Configure::write('branch',$id);
```

**FooController.php**

```
$branchId = Configure::read('branch');
```

---

I'm not sure if this is the right way. Is this a session variable or just a config? Can this variable be overwritten by other users?

What I read in the [Cookbook](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html) was, that I can use:

```
Configure::write('Session', [
    'defaults' => 'php'
]);
```

and then read the variable in any controller:

```
$this->request->session()->read('branch');
```

But where can I set 'branch'? Is this even possible in AppController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sessions is available](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object) everywhere you have access to the request object.

In other words, set your branch where you want (or where it's easy for you).
For example, I think it's better for you to do something like this:.

In your `App.php` **initialise** your "Branch" value like this

```
Configure::write('branch',$id);
```

In your `AppController`, inside `beforeFilter` function check if the session exists, otherwise, use the config value like this

```
if(!$this->request->session()->read('branch')){
    $this->request->session()->write('branch', Configure::read('branch'));
}
```

And in your `fooController` just use `$this->request->session()->read('branch');` and `$this->request->session()->write('branch', 'value');`

But you can also read and write the session inside View or Cell...

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. But something is missing. I cannot use $this->Session in my AppController, even with 'use Cake\Network\Session;' :(

Comment: Got it! I've used request->session() in my AppController: 
$this->request->session()>read('branch');